# Kendo Grid Gives Multiple Call To remote data when scroll down

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

1. Set server paging true for Kendo Data source
2. Set Page Size 300 for Kendo Datasource
3. Set Virtual scroll true for kendo grid
4. Now make sure in grid has 6000+ records
5. Scroll down grid to middle (such that you want to see 300 record on 50th page)

If you observe in browser, kendo grid data source call to get records for each page still the 50th page arrived.

Comment: Is there something you need a help with or you just saying ?

Comment: I need a help to solve my kendo grid issue.We are loading thousands of record at a time .So We kept server paging true because of performance issue.But because this we getting above mentioned issue.

Comment: I don't have 6000+ I have this kendo example http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@vojtiik/IroY, could you please explain what is happening and what are you expecting ? I am sorry I still don't understand what the issue is, what do you mean by the 50th page still arrived ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will call for every page if you don't move the scroller fast.

**Kendo says following about [virtualization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-scrollable.virtual) :** If set to true the grid will always display a single page of data. Scrolling would just change the data which is currently displayed.

There is an existing [issue](http://www.telerik.com/forums/remote-virtualization-making-two-calls-for-each-page-on-scrolling) with multiple requests during fast scroll.

**If you want to limit performance hit and you don't want to always load 300:**

1. make page size smaller - in this case the virtualization is quite likely going to skip some pages. However this relies at the users skill to scroll fast, if they scroll slow all the pages will be loaded.
2. implement server side paging via pager and avoid virtualization- this will allow you to control what are you getting from the server.